# Recognize each request thread in Servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

Is there any way to stop new client requests to servlet until old client request finishes execution in servlet? I do not want to use the `synchronized` keyword, instead I would like to recognize each request thread in servlet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding the requirement. Do you **really** want to restrict the servlet usage to 1 simultaneous request on an application wide basis? Or do you want to restrict to 1 request on a session wide basis? (i.e. 1 simultaneous request per browser session)? In any case, **why**? Is your servlet not threadsafe or something? Or is it a long running job which should not be re-executed until it is finished?

Comment: Dear BalusC ,  what I want  is : , how can I identify each thread come to my servlet  ??  and mange them the way I  like

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're *asking* as in "how do I achieve this solution?", but I don't understand what you *really need* as in "what is the proper solution for this?". The functional requirement is totally unclear. I don't want to post answers how to achieve an utterly wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I would guess it should be possible to store a bool in the Context.
Any arriving request checks the context-bool (let's name it "bBusy").
The first arriving request sets it and resets it when it has been handled.
The second arriving one checks : If first one is still being handled, it will be recognized and then it's up to your phantasy what to happen... :)

I hope that is what you were thinking of?

EDIT:
It has to be the correct context. My Servlet-times are somewhat long ago ... I guess ApplicationContext? - Not sure about that but you should be able to find it out by yourself.

Comment: your idea is good sofar but  do you  mean store boolean in servlet context ?

Comment: but  what  about  the second question ,  when I use keyword assert in my web application  it does not work :(

Comment: ServletContext is possible. Whatever context is shared by requests. I've done nothing with servlets in a while, so sorry 'bout my fading memory.
I've no idea 'bout that assert - issue you got there, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the synchronized keyword in your servlet or in a filter. In the servlet methods you can write:

   ```
   synchronized(this) {
      //code handling the request that will be executed 
      //by only one thread/request at a time
   }
   ```
2. You can use an object that will provide the synchronization for you (depending on your needs) - see java.util.concurrent
3. You can try to use an algorithm for thread synchronization without using the primitives. (CS classes usually tell such algorithms)
4. You can try to configure your server to execute the requests sequentially.
   See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/executor.html

Comment: @Tahani wrote : "please do \[no\]t ask me to use synchronize keyword" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a AtomicBoolean/volatile in the servletcontext in a synchronized block can achieve the effect. Another way is to use the SingleThreadModel interface ( deprecated) but it still does the Job.

I am still wondering why do you want to do this.

You can use assert in the web application code (servlets etc). But make sure the web/app server is started with the -ea or corresponding arguments that controls the assertions.

Comment: how  can I make sure that  the  server is started with the -ea or corresponding arguments that controls the assertions.

Comment: For most servers it is part of the command line while starting the server.  Please refer this link as well http://www.coderanch.com/t/82690/Tomcat/enable-JDK-assertions-Tomcat